# How To Extract .flv Stream from JW Player 5.1?

Tags: flash, reverse-engineering, jwplayer, cracking, flv

The problem is I've a slow internet connection, and the video doesn't buffer like in YouTube. Therefore I was wondering weather I can extract the url of the .flv file which is being streamed in JW Player and directly download it. Doing some preliminary research, I've found the following info:

- Main Video URL: http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/video/2263
- Link Only To Video: [http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/js/mediaplayer.swf?...](http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/js/mediaplayer.swf?config=http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/ijf10config.xml&file=http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/xml/video/2263)
- XML File: http://ijf10.ilcannocchiale.tv/xml/video/2263
- Actual File Name: `20100425_mother.flv`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31705/downloading-video-from-swf

Answer (score 13):

`rtmpdump` and `rtmpsuck` worked well for me. The trick is finding the relevant options for `rtmpdump`

Detailed instructions can be found here: http://pclosmag.com/html/issues/201104/page19.html

It comes down to this:

1. (root) `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -m owner \! --uid-owner root -j REDIRECT`
2. (root) `rtmpsuck`
3. browser, go to relevant page, play video
4. in the root terminal you should get the needed options for `rtmpdump`
5. (root) `iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -m owner \! --uid-owner root -j REDIRECT`
6. run `rtmpdump` with the relevant options

Note that if it's a live stream you might need to give the `--live` option to `rtmpdump`.

Answer (score 4):

try using this firefox extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006?src=api
it lets you save most flv, or other video files on the net.

Answer (score 2):

RTMPdump works perfectly.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/rtmp_dump_helper.html allows you to easily use RTMPdump with Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the url, and the m3u8 playlist, then you can use VLC to save the stream.

1. Media -> Convert/Save
2. Network [tab]
3. Past url "http://example.com/video_6.mp4/playlist.m3u8
4. Click "Convert/Save" button at bottom.
5. Browse for local save target path. Include extension, .mp4
6. In Settings/Profile section on same tab,

   1. Create new
   2. Name it "Original MP4 Content"
   3. Encapsulation: Select "MP4/MOV"
   4. Video Codec: Select Video. Select Keep original...

      1. Codec: H-264
      2. bitrate, framerate, scale, width, height = 0.
   5. Audio Codec: Select Audio. Select Keep original...

      1. Codec: MPEG Audio
      2. Bitrate: 128kbps
      3. Channels: 2
      4. Sample Rate: 44100
   6. Click the Save button.
7. Select "Original MP4 Content" that you just created.
8. Click the Start button at the bottom of the form.

... wait. It will download the video and assemble it. ...enjoy.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but this worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This file is actually being streamed over RTMP, so there isn't any FLV to download per-se.

Unfortunately, unless you use some sketchy tools like RTMPdump, there's no way to download it.