# How to capture video from Jwplayer?

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp

I am currently trying to capture a streaming video served by Jwplayer on a Wowza server ; I followed the beginning of this link answer : [How To Extract .flv Stream from JW Player 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792862/how-to-extract-flv-stream-from-jw-player-5-1)

The thing is, when I launch "rtmpsuck" with the local redirection, I get an error : `Error loading stream : manifest not found or invalid.`

And now, even without rtmpsuck, I can't launch any video from the website...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It's http://www.matele.tv/ ; don't worry about wich page, any of the video is similar, so if you have an technique for one..; )

Comment: Where are you running the player?

Comment: In Firefox ? (For example "Toutes les émissions" -> "Les directs")

Comment: I mean a link to where this is running.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I can't ; website is full ajax :/

Comment: I understand, I just don't have any idea what could be going on here without seeing.

Comment: Yeah but I can't give you any link except the homepage :/ (http://matele.tv) ; Then you just have to clic on one of the big icons (like "reportage") and you'll see the player

Comment: Ok, I did that. The player works fine here though using RTMP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rtmpdump \
  -r rtmp://176.31.227.113/matele/_definst_/mp4:jite-2013-06-25-1500.m4v \
  -o a.flv
RTMPDump v2.4-84-gdd57cd0
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
Starting download at: 0.000 kB
[...]
1152.119 kB / 5.92 sec (3.4%)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you please tell me the way to do it ? 'Cause I would like to apply it to another video, but I don't have its name.. ;)

Comment: Okay I found it with the exchanges between page and jwplayer, thanks !